# ASP.Net MVC - Rhino Mocks - Expected method call parameters

Tags: asp.net, mocking, rhino

I am setting a expectation on a method which has a object as the parameter. This object will be created inside the called functionality. When I mock this I get an error saying Expected #1 Actual #0

How to resolve this ?

Code:

Customer testObject = new Customer();
Expect.Call(sampleRepository.Find(testObject)).Return(True);

I am suspecting creating a new object makes this expectation fail.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "IgnoreArguments" method:

```
Customer testObject = new Customer(); Expect.Call(sampleRepository.Find(testObject)).IgnoreArguments().Return(True);
```

This tells Rhino.Mocks to just expect a call on "Find" and you don't care what the parameters are.

Comment: Thanks patrick. That worked fine. But from testing point of view how can we assume that parameters are received successfully.

Comment: You indicated this parameter that is passed to sampleRepository.Find() is created internally, inside the method you're calling.  This means its a private implementation detail and not something you should be testing.  It will lead to your implementation leaking into your tests.  So if you ever change implementation, you'll break your unit tests.

Comment: If you REALLY need to check the arguments sent to sampleRepository.Find(), you can use the "GetArgumentsForCallsMadeOn" method on your sampleRepository mock.  It'll return an array of arrays.  The first element [0] is an array of params called the first time the method was invoked, element [1] is an array of params called the second time the method was invoked, etc...

Answer (score 1):

In additional to Patrick's answer, you can use `Constraints()` to check properties on the object without having to check the object instance itself. Each argument to `Constraints` is the constraint for the actual argument at that position (you can use `&&` or `||` to multiple constraints to combine them):

```
Customer testObject = new Customer();

Expect.Call(sampleRepository.Find(testObject))
    .Constraints(
        Is.NotNull() && Property.Value("Nickname", "SnakeEyes")
    )
    .Return(True);
```

Comment: Thanks Richard for this useful info .